# How to get the size of single document in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, document, objectid, objectsize

I encountered a strange behavior of mongo and I would like to clarify it a bit...
My request is simple as that: I would like to get a size of single document in collection.
I found two possible solutions:

- Object.bsonsize - some javascript method that should return a size in bytes
- db.collection.stats() - where there is a line 'avgObjSize' that produce some "aggregated"(average) size view on the data. It simply represents average size of single document.
  When I create test collection with only one document, both functions returns different values. How is it possible?
  Does it exist some other method to get a size of a mongo document?

Here, I provide some code I perform testing on:

1. I created new database 'test' and input simple document with only one attribute: type:"auto"

   ```
   db.test.insert({type:"auto"})
   ```
2. output from stats() function call: *db.test.stats()*:

   ```
   { 
     "ns" : "test.test",
     "count" : 1,
     "size" : 40,
     "avgObjSize" : 40,
     "storageSize" : 4096,
     "numExtents" : 1,
     "nindexes" : 1,
     "lastExtentSize" : 4096,
     "paddingFactor" : 1,
     "systemFlags" : 1,
     "userFlags" : 0,
     "totalIndexSize" : 8176,
     "indexSizes" : {
           "_id_" : 8176
   },
   "ok" : 1
   ```

   }
3. output from bsonsize function call: *Object.bsonsize(db.test.find({test:"auto"}))*

   ```
   481
   ```

Answer (score 226, accepted):

In the previous call of `Object.bsonsize()`, Mongodb returned the size of the cursor, rather than the document.

Correct way is to use this command:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne())
```

With `findOne()`, you can define your query for a specific document:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({type:"auto"}))
```

This will return the correct size (in bytes) of the particular document.

Comment: How to get the size of a list of document with query?

Comment: But of course this code will fetch the document before calculating the size.

Comment: This not return a goood size :(... But this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/40993183/3933634

Comment: How to get Object.bsonsize, what is the import or required statement?

Comment: For anyone else who missed it, **you must use `findOne` instead of `find`**

Comment: how to do it in python?

Comment: For anyone else who missed it, **you must use `findOne` or `find().toArray()` instead of `find`** Using `find().toArray()` of course gives the size **sum** of all documents.

Answer (score 71):

**MAXIMUM DOCUMENT SIZE 16 MiB ([source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-size-limit))**

---

**If you have version >=4.4 (`$bsonSize` [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/))**

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "size_bytes": { "$bsonSize": "$$ROOT" },
      "size_KB": { "$divide": [{"$bsonSize": "$$ROOT"}, 1000] },
      "size_MB": { "$divide": [{"$bsonSize": "$$ROOT"}, 1000000] }
    }
  }
])
```

---

**If you have version <4.4 (`Object.bsonSize()` [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#std-label-shell-quick-ref-misc))**

You can use this script for get a real size:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(obj)
{
  var size = Object.bsonsize(obj);
  print('_id: '+obj._id+' || Size: '+size+'B -> '+Math.round(size/(1000))+'KB -> '+Math.round(size/(1000*1000))+'MB (max 16MB)');
});
```

Note: If your IDs are 64-bit integers, the above will truncate the ID value on printing! If that's the case, you can use instead:

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(obj)
{
  var size = Object.bsonsize(obj);
  var stats =
  {
    '_id': obj._id, 
    'bytes': size, 
    'KB': Math.round(size/(1000)), 
    'MB': Math.round(size/(1000*1000))
  };
  print(tojson(stats));
});
```

This also has the advantage of returning JSON, so a GUI like RoboMongo can tabulate it!

---

**edit : thanks to [@zAlbee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2646919/zalbee) for your suggest completion.**

Comment: This is exactly what i am looking for but it not working maybe related with my mongo version. current one is 3.4 ?

Comment: Anyone else getting `TypeError: Object.bsonsize is not a function` ?

Comment: Do you have try in mongo shell ? It's work : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/#miscellaneous

Comment: Proper label would be rather `'KiB': Math.round(size/(1024)), 'MiB': Math.round(size/(1024*1024))` (or `'kB': Math.round(size/(1000)), 'MB': Math.round(size/(1000*1000))`

Comment: `print(tojson(stats));` edit queue is full -.-

Answer (score 37):

The effective amount of space the document will take in the collection will be more than the size of your document because of the [Record Padding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/record-padding/) mechanism.

This is why there is a difference between the outputs of the `db.test.stats()` and `Object.bsonsize(..)`.

To get the **exact** size (in bytes) of the document, stick to the `Object.bsonsize()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in that case, I have another question regarding this issue: 
suppose I have a collection where documents with long list of identifiers are saved in the form of the list. (identifiers are stored originally in txt-csv file- with size 300 kB; each identifier is 10characters long)
When I run _bsonsize_ on such a document the size is even lower than 481.
It returns 465. Could you explain to me this situation, please?

Comment: Which size is used to enforce the mongDB document size limitation? Object.bsonsize()?

Comment: The MongoDB document size is a constraint of the Mongo, this is covered in the manual on their web site, 16MB. I have hit this limit a number of times trying import records.

Answer (score 16):

With mongodb **4.4** (upcoming), You can use [**`bsonSize`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/bsonSize/) operator to get the document size.

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "object_size": { "$bsonSize": "$$ROOT" }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 4):

Method `Object.bsonsize()` is available only in legacy `mongo` shell. In new `mongosh` you have to use package [bson](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson) or [mongocompat snippets](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongosh-snippets/tree/main/snippets/mongocompat)

```
const BSON = require("bson");

BSON.calculateObjectSize({field: "value"})

BSON.calculateObjectSize(db.test.findOne())
```

Answer (score 3):

Object.bsonsize(db.test.findOne({type:"auto"}))
It gives in bytes.

Comment: Try to explain your answer . .