# How to get size of mongodb single document in bytes using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm fetching a document using db.coll.findOne. I wanted to get size of the document in bytes using nodejs with only mongo-native driver.can it be possible?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008822/mongo-get-size-of-single-document ?

Comment: "Object.bsonsize" execute only in mongoshell i need to get size of document in node.js application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using [BSON](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/bson.html#bson-calculateobjectsize) (it's a dependency of the mongodb driver):

```
var bson = require("bson");
var BSON = new bson.BSONPure.BSON();

db.coll.findOne(query).then(function(err, doc) {
  var size = BSON.calculateObjectSize(doc);
});
```

Comment: i was able to get size values.but it differs from "Object.bsonsize" value is there any reason for the difference in size?

Comment: I don't know why exactly but a guess: `Object.bsonsize()` returns the true size of the stored document, `calculateObjectSize()` will only try to calculate it (the name is a good indicator :p) so anything thing can lead to a different calculated size.

Comment: I had to change it to `new bson.BSON()` to get it working. I guess the api changed since 2013.