# Calculate BSONObj size before storing to mongo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, bson

I'm trying to figure out, how to calculate size before storing some data to MongoDB. Since I wrote a script that parses data, combining them in a single document and trying to do `instance.save()`.

So far I am getting an error such as:

```
BSONObj size: 17102819 (0x104F7E3) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)
```

I don't want to use gridFS, because it is architecture-dependent and the project is big enough to use it, so far I decided to skip such documents that have a greater size than required.

I found the article about: `How to calculate existing document BSONSize`

Link to the article: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-calculate-mongodb-document-size-in-node-js-f463b8457f27

But, I need to figure out, how to calculate it before storing it in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Object.bsonsize({field: "value"})
-> 22
```

Look like this method is available only in legacy shell `mongo` but not in new `mongosh`. For `mongosh`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34768008/3027266

Comment: Exactly! But i need to calculate it in runtime before saving to mongo, I composed the document, and before saving, I want to check the BSONsize

Comment: Yes, pass your object this method and check the size.