# How to find the fhe size of the specific Document in MonogoDB Collection?

Tags: mongodb, memory, mongodb-query

I have 100k documents in an MonoDB Collection, the `document({id : '789736363828292'})` has 20k Documents/Records. I would like find the memory utilized by that particular document.

Please help me to find the memory size in MB in MongoDB console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo = get size of single document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008822/mongo-get-size-of-single-document)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Object.bsonsize` in MongoShell which will return a BSON size (in **bytes**) of one document. Try

```
Object.bsonsize(db.col.findOne({id : '789736363828292'}))
```

Comment: @Rocky why do you want to add a date range ? `Object.bsonsize` takes one and exactly one document.

Comment: For anyone else who missed it, **you must use `findOne` instead of `find`** to get the correct size