# Getting the size of single document in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and am trying to retrieve the size of a single document from a database.

The database is named "`enron`"
The collection is named "`email`"

I tried:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.email.findOne())
```

I also tried:

```
Object.bsonsize(db.enron.findOne())
```

But it only returns `0`.
How can I get the size of a document?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the size of single document in Mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008822/how-to-get-the-size-of-single-document-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the related question [How to get the size of a single document in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008822/how-to-get-the-size-of-single-document-in-mongodb)

Comment: I appreciate the link. However, I tried using Object.bsonsize(db.enron.findOne({type:"auto"})) and I still get 0 as the output. Any idea why thats happening?

Comment: I have not. What is the aggregate approach?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61452145/788798 this one